# python regression on time series

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series

I have a matrix containing 8 time series.

I want to build a model between their values at time `t` and their values at time `t-1, t-2,..., t-k`.

Let suppose for simplicity a linear model `sk.linear_model.LinearRegression` and the time series be: `X=np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, 8))`

How can I write code that uses the previous `k` values to estimate `X(t)`?  I also want to use the estimated `X(t)` to predict `X(t+1)`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide sample input and output snippets.

Comment: How big is your k, and how far past your last time value are you planning to extend the system?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if you want to do serious time-series analysis with Python, you should probably use a specific libaray like [statsmodels.tsa](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/tsa.html).

However, if you are insistent on using sklearn, you're going to need to set up your initial training set to fit your model to. If you're using k points to predict the next one, and have an 8-dimensional time series, then you should end up with k*8 features and 8 targets for your training set. Here's a sample with k set to 3.

```
import numpy as np
k = 3 #example
n = 1000
num_series = 8
raw_x = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n, num_series))
y = raw_x[k:] 
X = np.empty((n-k, k*num_series))
for i in xrange(n-k):
  X[i] = np.ravel(raw_x[i:i+k])
print X.shape, y.shape
```

which outputs

```
(997, 24) (997, 8)
```

for the shapes of the features and labels respectively, as desired.

You can then pass this x and y into any of sklearn's models that supports multiple targets (including LinearRegression). If you want to predict future points, you simply need to pass the appropriate data to the `predict` method of your fitted model.